# Spring Data MongoDB date format issue

Tags: mongodb, date, spring-data

I am having a problem handling dates between my java server and mongodb. I am using Spring Data with MongoDB. My java code is deployed in Tomcat on a linux environment.
I have verified that the server time on my Java linux box is the same as the linux box on which MongoDB is running.

A simple example to find an object gives me a discrepancy in the last modified date field.

```
public Note getNoteById(String noteId) {

    Query q = new Query().addCriteria(Criteria.where("_id").is(noteId));
    return mongoTemplate.findOne(q, Note.class);

}
```

In the `Note` class, I have a last modified field which is a java `Date`. However, when I retrieve the java object, I see that the last modified date is 6-7 hours different from the Database value.

```
@Document(collection = "notes")
public class Note {

    @Indexed
    private String id;

    private String title;

    private Date lastModifiedDate;
    ...
```

The database value for the last modified date field is `ISODate("2016-05-09T18:51:02.000Z")`. However, when I read the `Note` document in Java, I see that the `Note` object in Java has a date of `Mon May 09 11:51:02 PDT 2016` which is 7 hours different from the DB value.

Can you please help?

Comment: It's not 7 hours different. It's the same date with -7 hours offset (PDT vs. IST).

Comment: Thanks Ori. How can I handle this? Any thoughts?

Comment: If you want to set it for the JVM level, use `-Duser.timezone=UTC`. This, however, will impose a global timezone change. Alternatively, you can use an [onAfterConvert](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongodb.mapping-usage.events) event, where you can use an appropriate instance of `TimeZone` to convert the date as will.

Comment: Thank you Ori. however I have the following problem. I am in the afterConvert event, the date is already converted to a PDT timezone (based on my JVM). I need to reconvert this PDT Date into a UTC Date and set it on the object. For example, <code> @Override
    public void onAfterConvert(DBObject dbo, Note source) { ... } </code> . The problme here is that the source.getLastModifiedDate is already in PDT. I need this to be changed to UTC. Date Formatters dont help because when I parse it into a Date, it again changes it to PDT using my JVM timezone. How can I handle this?

Comment: [Please see an example here](http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-convert-date-and-time-between-timezone/)